# What is the Big O time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

We are given $m$ arrays of $n$ elements each. For 90% of these arrays we run an $\mathcal O(n)$ algorithm and for the other 10% an $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ algorithm. What is the total time complexity? I think it is $\mathcal O(m n \log n)$ but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you think that? Without your thought process, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

The O(n log n) eventually grows faster than the O(n) algorithm. We always take the fastest growing component of the algorithm when deciding the complexity, so you're right that the total complexity of the algorithm is O(m n log(n))

Comment: It's worth noting that the fractions .9 and .1 are immaterial, as long as they're nonzero.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, i dont speak English so i will be concise:

m * 90 / 100 = m'

m * 10 / 100 = m''

=> O(m'·n·log(n)) + O(m''·n) = O(m'·n·log(n) + m''·n)

=> O(m'·n·log(n))

Comment: Shouldn't $m'$ be in the O(m''•n)?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: sorry, actually don't

Comment: I see a calculation, but no reasoning.

Comment: Correct me then, please.